# Heroku doesn't download new npm packages

Tags: heroku, npm

I have a Heroku dyno running my React application.  I have added npm packages since my last push to my local instance of the site.  When I push to Heroku, it deploys but it is missing the packages and throws ReferenceErrors saying the packages don't exist.

The packages are in `package.json`.  What could be the reason Heroku is not detecting the new packages?

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing `heroku` from caching your node_modules. i.e:

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false -a YOUR_APP_NAME`

This command forces `heroku` to install your `package.json` afresh after every new build.